# Can't connect to my own wifi network

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I use ubuntu 12.04 on various differents laptops/netbooks on my home. I was able to connect to my own wifi network. But sometimes, I couldn't connect to my wifi network, it ask me for password again and again. After many tries (a lot of them), sometimes I can connect, but sometimes I can't. I have this problem with a Samsung netbook and with a HP laptop. Right now, I can't connect with the HP laptop. I'll be grateful for any help.

Best regards,

Nicolás

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening with both your laptops then there must be a problem with the signal. It happens often with me also. you should speak to whoever is responsible for the network.